# List all record with count of third table but 2nd table is pivot table - MySQL Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables `business`, `deal_business`, `deal`.

`business` table has `id`, `name`, `address` etc (each business has 1 row)

`deal_business` is a pivot table, it has two FK columns `business_id, deal_id` (Against one business, It can have multiple rows)

`deal` table has `id`, `title`, `desc`, `start_date`, `expiry date` (Business can have multiple deals)

I want to query to get all business with a count of total active deals based on start_date and expiry date.

I want something like this.

| `id` | business Name | total_active deals etc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KFC | 5 |
| 1 | McDonalds | 7 |

In the above scenario, KFC has 5 active deals right now and McDonald's has 7 active deals. But they also have many inactive deals. I want to show only active.

I am using Laravel 8. Here is how I am doing it.

I fetch all business only, then I loop through the data. Inside the loop, I use a *left join* query with the deal_business and deal table. It gets the correct result. But it is very slow.

Because if there is 500 business, the loop runs 500 times, and then the query inside the loop runs 500 times too.

Is there a better way to do it using relations? Eloquent or direct MySQL database query? Any help would be appreciated.

```php
$business = Business::all();

foreach ($business as $busi) {
    // getting count from other table here.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps writing the plain SQL first:

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.name, count(d.id)
FROM business b
  JOIN deal_business db ON b.id=db.business_id
  JOIN deal d ON db.deal_id=d.id
WHERE now BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.expiry_date
GROUP BY b.id, b.name
```

One way to express this with Laravel's [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) is:

```php
$result = DB::table("business")
    ->addSelect("business.id", "business.name")
    ->selectRaw("count(deal.id)")
    ->join("deal_business", "business.id", "=", "deal_business.business_id")
    ->join("deal", "deal_business.deal_id", "=", "deal.id")
    ->whereRaw("now() BETWEEN deal.start_date AND deal.expiry_date")
    ->groupBy("business.id", "business.name")
    ->get();
```

Comment: is it possible get expired deals count as well using same query?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I do not know if using subqueries for the counts would improve performance e.g. `SELECT b.id, b.name, (SELECT count(d.id) FROM deal d JOIN deal_business db ON db.deal_id=d.id WHERE db.business_id=b.id AND now BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.expiry_date) AS deals_active, (SELECT <same select and join> WHERE db.business_id=b.id AND now > d.expiry_date) AS deals_expired`.

Comment: Ok i will try using that query, Thanks